# Inplementación IsValid en DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, mvc

He creado una annotation personalizadas para un campo y al enviar el formulario me lanza este error

> Esta clase no ha implementado IsValid(object value). El punto de
>   entrada preferido es GetValidationResult() y las clases deben
>   invalidar IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context).

El codigo es este

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public class NombreApellidos : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected bool Nombre(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var v = (VmVisitaParking)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
            int idV = int.Parse(v.IdVisitanteParking.ToString());
            if (idV>0)
            {
                VyosaByDBEntities db = new VyosaByDBEntities();

                var visitanteExistente = db.VisitanteParking.Where(vi => vi.IdVisitanteParking == idV).ToList();
                v.Nombre = visitanteExistente.First().Nombre;
                v.Apellidos = visitanteExistente.First().Apellidos;
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true; 

        }
}
```

Y el ViewModel

```
public string IdVisitanteParking { get; set; }

[NombreApellidos(ErrorMessage = "Introduzca un nombre")]
public string Nombre { get; set; }
```

No tengo muy claro a que se debe ese error y como solucionarlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes sobre escribir el metodo IsValid.

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
```

y retonar un ValidationResult en caso de error, en caso de que todo sea correcto retorna null o ValidationResult.Success que es lo mismo.

Como debería ser tu código mas o menos:

```
    public class NombreApellidos : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var v = (VmVisitaParking)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
            int idV = int.Parse(v.IdVisitanteParking.ToString());
            if (idV > 0)
            {
                VyosaByDBEntities db = new VyosaByDBEntities();

                var visitanteExistente = db.VisitanteParking.Where(vi => vi.IdVisitanteParking == idV).ToList();
                v.Nombre = visitanteExistente.First().Nombre;
                v.Apellidos = visitanteExistente.First().Apellidos;
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
            }

            return null;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto, gracias